# keep executing when cliking button. DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'd like to make the code keep changing not executes only once.
as a default, the button has a dark mode for text, and the background color is pink.
when you click the button, the background color will be black and the text in the button
will be light mode.

id like to make it when you click the button with a light mode,
it will vice versa.
how can I keep calling the function?

```js
function changeLight() {
  const btnTag = document.createElement('button');
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
  btnTag.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  btnTag.textContent = "dark mode";
  btnTag.style.color = "black";

  btnTag.onclick = function() {
    if(btnTag.textContent = "light mode") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
        btnTag.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        btnTag.textContent = "dark mode";
        btnTag.style.color = "black";
    }
    if(btnTag.textContent = "dark mode") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        btnTag.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
        btnTag.textContent = "light mode";
        btnTag.style.color = "white";
    }
  }

  document.body.appendChild(btnTag);
};
changeLight();
```

Comment: use `toggle`. and your if statements have a single `=` which is used for assigning values not evaluating them

Comment: This should just be adding and removing a class.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing "===" inside if condition. I added else block and it works

```
  btnTag.onclick = function(e) {
    if(btnTag.textContent === "light mode") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
        btnTag.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        btnTag.textContent = "dark mode";
        btnTag.style.color = "black";
    } else 
    if (btnTag.textContent === "dark mode") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        btnTag.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
        btnTag.textContent = "light mode";
        btnTag.style.color = "white";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement should compare with `==`, not assign with `=`. Also, put a `debugger()` or a [breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints) in the code and go through each line of code one row after another.

You would have then seen that the code goes into the first if statement, after the second click, and then the second one, because you changed the text to "dark mode".

You need to add `else` in front of your second if statement:

```
else if (btnTag.textContent == "dark mode") {
```

```js
function changeLight() {
  const btnTag = document.createElement('button');
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
  btnTag.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  btnTag.textContent = "dark mode";
  btnTag.style.color = "black";

  btnTag.onclick = function() {
    if(btnTag.textContent == "light mode") { // CHANGED
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
        btnTag.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        btnTag.textContent = "dark mode";
        btnTag.style.color = "black";
    }
    else if (btnTag.textContent == "dark mode") { // CHANGED
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        btnTag.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
        btnTag.textContent = "light mode";
        btnTag.style.color = "white";
    }
  }

  document.body.appendChild(btnTag);
};
changeLight();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `===` or `==` for comparison, instead of `=`. You had used it in your if condition.

This should work -

```
function changeLight() {
  const btnTag = document.createElement('button');
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
  btnTag.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  btnTag.textContent = "dark mode";
  btnTag.style.color = "black";

  btnTag.onclick = function() {
    if(btnTag.textContent === "light mode") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
        btnTag.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        btnTag.textContent = "dark mode";
        btnTag.style.color = "black";
    }
    if(btnTag.textContent === "dark mode") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        btnTag.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
        btnTag.textContent = "light mode";
        btnTag.style.color = "white";
    }
  }

  document.body.appendChild(btnTag);
};
changeLight();
```

Remember,

- `=` for assignment
- `==` for comparison by value
- `===` for comparison by type and value